# Unable to produce HTML reports in protractor 3.3.0 with protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Tags: protractor

i am new to protractor testing.

i was using protractor with protractor-html-screenshot-reporter and i used to generate html reports.

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
baseDirectory: '/protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
```

but when i upgraded my protractor version to 3.3.0, i am unable to produce these reports anymore by using protractor-html-screenshot-reporter module.

i may be missing some or the other configurations or is it not compatible with the protractor 3.3.0 version

any response would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which version of protractor were you using before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` is not compatible with jasmine 2. Latest versions of protractor come with `Jasmine2` by default.You can use -
**`protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter`**

for Json report you need to add `resultJsonOutputFile` in your `config` file.

```
  resultJsonOutputFile: 'Path to your Report.json'
```

Code Snippet of `conf.js`

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');  

exports.config = {
directConnect: true, //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
baseUrl: 'http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/',
framework: 'jasmine2',
specs: ['*spec.js '],
allScriptsTimeout: 180000,
getPageTimeout: 180000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
},
resultJsonOutputFile: './Report.json', // here you need to put the json option
onPrepare: function () {
    var width = 1300;
    var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './test/reports/'
        }));
  }
 };
```

**NOTE**: First install ***protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter*** package by running '**_npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter**' from command prompt.  Otherwise it will give error 'protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter' Not found

Comment: Thanks for the response.

i have tried protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter with protractor 3.3.0 and it is working fine also.

but with protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter i am only able to produce HTML reports but not the JSON report for each test like we used to get with protractor-html-screenshot-reporter module.

any idea to generate those JSON logs with protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter module

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support!

i have tried the mentioned idea but unable to generate the json file, it would be really great if you can share the sample code snippet.

           jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
   savePath: '../Report/HTML/',
   takeScreenshots: true,
   takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
   fixedScreenshotName: true,
   filePrefix: 'protractor-tests-report-'+ timeStamp,
   resultJsonOutputFile: '../Report/report.json'
  }));

i have used like shown above.

Comment: you need to put it as a separate key, attached sample conf.js!

Comment: Thanks, i could able to generate HTML results along with the JSON summary logs.

one more doubt i have now, if there any way to add Environment details like OS, Browser name and version to the JSON logs?

since if we try to run the same test against various browsers so we would surely need that details to be logged somewhere for better reporting.

any suggestions here.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, if you have a new question please raise a new question.In that way this question would not be deviated, also please accept the answer as it would help others having this same question!